# Want to create multiple okta groups programatically

Tags: okta-api

What is the best way to create large number of groups in Okta? I want to basically create a number of groups in Okta. Since the quantity is high i am looking at some utility/option to create all the groups in one go.

Comment: What language are you looking to use? The official Okta SDKs support creating groups.

Comment: Thanks @BrianDemers, i will go through the SDK. https://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/groups.html

Comment: OKTA doesn't support multiple record creation. Neither for users nor for groups. We can create multiple groups by calling the POST API for group creation multiple times.